# Как исправить ошибку при подключении БД Access к PHP?

Tags: php, odbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД Access и возникает ошибка:

> "Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in D:\ampps\Ampps\www\connect\index.php on line 11

Уже пробовала поставить пользовательский и системный dsn 32/64, пробовала указать 4 параметр в odbc_connect - SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER, пробовала прописать к какому именно dsn подключиться "Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accbd);Dbq=recruter".

Код:

```
$connection = odbc_connect(
   "Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accbd);Dbq=recruter", 
   "", 
   "",
   SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER
);
```

Ошибка всё та же

Comment: `"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accbd)};Dbq=recruter", ` [Example #1 DSN-less connections (Microsoft Access)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо, но все равно ошибка. Буду разбираться

Comment: (*.mdb, *.accbd) расширение файла одно оставьте

Comment: @InDevX тоже не помогло, может ли быть проблема с драйверам? Я читала на одном сайте, что возможно их необходимо обновить или нет?

Comment: https://community.progress.com/s/article/3352?q=%22Data%20source%20name%20not%20found%20and%20no%20default%20driver%20specified%22  не факт что обновить, там хватает возможных причин